# Visual Studio 2010 include files in the exe

Tags: c#

i have a simple question: I am using Visual Studio 2010 (I need this version for a special framework that does not work with a newer version) and i'd like to generate a standalone-exe without any extra files.

The project itself includes some small images as PNG-files and a few other files.

When i compile the program, there is a content-directory with all my files inside. I tried to search the options for any options but i was not successful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add your files as an embedded resource and you will have them inside the exe.

Right click on the file in the Solution Explorer -> Properties -> Build Action -> Embedded Resource.

Also you can check this MSDN article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292

Comment: Tip: If you have any trouble determining the correct resource path, inspect your assembly using a decompiler like dotPeek.

Comment: Also, the example is nice but it bizarrely has streams as class fields—it would be annoying to keep track of their states.